# How do I pass arrays of values to SudzC-generated webservice classes?

Tags: objective-c, soap, ios4, touchxml, sudzc

I have a sudzc service class generated from a WSDL that accepts an ArrayOfInt and ArrayOfString objects as parameters. The service method signature is this:

```
- (SoapRequest*) Search: (id <SoapDelegate>) handler filters: (NSMutableArray*) displayedAttributes: (NSMutableArray*) displayedAttributes;
```

My question is, how do I pass values into the parameters that expect NSMutableArrays?

In the above method signature, the "displayedAttributes" parameter is expecting an `ArrayOfInt` object (which should be populated with several integers in an int tag, e.g., `<int>1</int><int>2</int><int>3</int>` etc).

However none of these things which I've tried have worked:

- Directly passing an NSArray/NSMutableArray of (int) objects
- Directly passing an NSArray/NSMutableArray of NSNumber objects
- Passing an array of strings containing @"1", @"2", @"3" etc
- Passing an array of strings that already contain `@"<int>1</int>"`, `@"<int>2</int>"`, etc
- Constructing a `CXMLDocument` out of a string based on the integers

I'm sure this is somehow explained in the accompanying documentation in the download -- it's just not clear to me at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

@Jon Limjap: Lucky you are!!! it asks you for a type which you have dealt before, I have custom class type that SudzC generated for me (!)... It initializes only when passed CXMLNode, (which need CXMLDocument / CXMLElement).. I have no idea how to deal with such type...

an instance is: filter is a class, I have a class of the filter, but there is no way to initialize it, (except alloc-init and then setting its properties, but its properties are another such custom type.. !!!!)...If you know any "trick" to tell/configure sudzc to allow us to pass objects or fetch objects of cocoa type, do tell me....

Answer (score 0):

I had similar situation of passing array of objects to SOAP request. I managed to get it working by doing following changes.

SOAP array case in not added in

```
+(NSString *) serialize: (id) object()
{
//look if it is array not implemented
}
```

so I managed to change in the following method

```
+ (NSString*) serialize: (id) object withName: (NSString*) nodeName {
    if([object respondsToSelector:@selector(serialize:)]) {
        if([object isKindOfClass:[SoapArray class]]) 
            return [object serialize:object];
        return [object serialize: nodeName];
    }
    NSString *temp =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<%@>%@</%@>", nodeName, [Soap serialize: object], nodeName];
    NSLog(@"serialise = %@", temp);
    return temp;
}
```

at the time SOAP request,

```
NSMutableArray arr = [[MYTable_STUB_ARR alloc] init]

MYTABLE_OBJ *obj = [[MYTABLE_OBJ alloc] init];

[arr addObject:obj];

[obj release];
```

Pass element arr object your SOAP Request ??

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit old, but I hope it will help someone. I implemented the `serialize:` method on SoapArray this way:

```
- (NSMutableString *)serialize:(NSString *)name
{
    NSMutableString *str = [NSMutableString string];
    //[str appendFormat:@"<%@>", name];
    for (id content in self)
    {
        //[str appendString:[Soap serialize:content]];
        [str appendString:[Soap serialize:content withName:name]];
    }
    //[str appendFormat:@"</%@>", name];
    return str;
}
```

As you can see, there are some commented lines. If you uncomment them and comment the currently used one inside the for, you will get a tag named name which will contain objects tagged with the content class name.